# .htaccess rewrite rule for a folder name which has multiple instances

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /reseller/(.*) /employee/$1
```

The problem is there is a sub-directory in another part of the filesystem also named `reseller`. This is also getting rewritten. I only want to rewrite the `reseller` directory at the top level, not the sub-directories.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to anchors in your regex to make it match only at start:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/reseller/(.*)$ /employee/$1
```